# How to find last business day excluding holidays as well

Tags: java

I wrote code in Java to find the last business day which works fine. It excludes saturday and sundays. But how to exclude even the national holidays in USA? Is there any library in Java that I can use ?

I don't want to hard code the holidays in arraylist and read from it. How to folks deal with this in general?

Comment: You will need to find something to define which holidays exist and you will need to choose which you are observing. Here is an implementation that has a few holidays: http://core0.staticworld.net/downloads/idge/imported/article/jvw/1998/01/holidays.java

Comment: And if you'd like to add to that, here's the article that goes with the mentioned source: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077543/learn-java/java-tip-44--calculating-holidays-and-their-observances.html

Comment: The best way I've ever read about to handle this is to create a datastore of custom `Day` objects with `boolean` (or equivalent type) attributes like `holidayUs`, `businessDay`, `weekend`, or whatever, and to query that datastore for your answer. An RDBMS like Derby or Postgres is useful for this, but an in-memory structure like a `Map` would work also. If there even is a formulaic way to derive the answer reliably, it'll be complicated and hard to maintain by comparison.

Answer (score 0):

There are java implementations of the various holidays and which days they fall on. If you are okay going over the network, there are a few paid or free API services which do something similar. The First one I found was https://holidayapi.com/